# Binding to new instance of ObservableCollection<T> doesnt update view

Tags: xaml, uwp, observablecollection

In my UWP app, my bound view gets updated when I clear the bound collection and fill it again, but it doesn't update when I instantiate a new collection

**This updates the view:**

```
if (CurrentPivotHeader != "author") AuthorFacets.Clear();
```

**This doesn't update the view:**

```
if (CurrentPivotHeader != "author") AuthorFacets = new ObservableCollection<IFacet>();
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind AuthorFacets , Mode=OneWay}"
                         Name="AuthorListBox"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple"
                         SelectionChanged="AuthorListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:IFacet">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Because of some other issues I cannot use the `Clear()` method. Is there a way to update the view on instantiation?

Comment: *"Because of some other issues I cannot use the `Clear()` method."* - Fix those issues then.

Comment: Show us your `AuthorFacets` implementation. I am almost certain you didn't notify property changes in its setter.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `AuthorFacets` property:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    private ObservableCollection<IFacet> _authorFacets;
    public ObservableCollection<IFacet> AuthorFacets
    {
        get { return _authorFacets; }
        set { _authorFacets = value;  RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AuthorFacets)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to implement `InotifyPropertyChanged` in the `IFacet` (Type) classes also or only on the `ObservableCollection` ? Because implementing it only on the ObservableCollections doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to implement in the class where the AuthorFacets source property is defined as per my answer.

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Then you are obviously doing something wrong. Please provide a full repo of your issue if you want anyone to be able to point out what: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.